# NSDateFormatter parses two-digit year as 2046 instead of 1946 or 2040 instead of 1940

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter, date-parsing

I have a scenario where I'm getting a date string as "46-05-24" (yy-mm-dd), and I need to re-format the date as "1946-05-24". The `NSDateFormatter` interprets the string as "2046-05-24".

I'm using this code:

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd"
    let gmt : NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!
    dateFormatter.timeZone = gmt
    let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date as String)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    if dateFromString != nil{
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)
        print(dateString)
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: have you tried just prepending `19` to the string before parsing it?

Comment: date i'm scanning from a document

Comment: As you have date : '46-05-24'. So, as per timestamp rule, it's starting from 1970. So, it may be taking current century 2000 as default

Comment: `mm` is minutes. `MM` is month.

Answer (score 5):

It happens because if you're giving `NSDateFormatter` a two-digit year, it needs to decide what century that year is in. It does this using its `twoDigitStartDate` property, which sets the earliest date that a two-digit year can represent. It has a default value of December 31, 1949. A date in 46 falls on the low side of 50 so it gets treated as 2046.

You can change the value of `twoDigitStartDate` to adjust the results. For example, you could set it to a date exactly 100 years in the past. That would mean that any two-digit year would be interpreted as the most recent year with those two digits:

```
let oneCenturyAgo = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Year, value: -100, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue:0))
dateFormatter.twoDigitStartDate = oneCenturyAgo
```

Of course if you get someone whose date is over 100 years ago, there's no good way for your code to know which year is appropriate. If the year is "10", was that person born in 1910 or 2010? You have no way of knowing, and all your code can do is make the best guess.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that your data omits some relevant information: the century. Using only the last two digits you as the dev have to decide which century the dates are in. If all of them are in the 20th century (1900 - 1999) you can use the following approach:

You could simply prepend `19` before the string to parse. Assuming `date` is the string that you want to parse you can use

```
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString("19" + (date as String))
```

instead of your

```
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date as String)
```

If the dates you are going to handle are in the 20th and the 21st century you are going to have a bad time because what year is `05` supposed to reflect? 1905? 2005? 2105?

Comment: what if the year is in 2 thousands, i mean the current century ?

Comment: @raki Then OP is going to have a bad time since `05` for example is not deterministic parseable - 1905 or 2005?. Using only 2 year digits will always get you into trouble because you loose some information. Using my code he will get the exact he result he is asking for: 20th century dates!

Comment: I'm getting the date from scanning a passport,so there are situations like tat. :(

Comment: @AnilSanto Situations like what? Post 1999 dates? Then you have to come up with a own logic to determine those.