# Using DateFormatter to show future dates instead of past dates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have the following code where input is being sent as `10/01/77` and `DateFormatter` is converting it into `1977` but the expected year is `2077`. How can this be controlled?

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
let _tmpDate = formatter.date(from: "10/01/77")
// _tmpDate is getting converted to 1977 instead of 2077
```

However, if the date is presented as `02/26/09`, the expected year is `2009` and not `2109`.

Comment: Look at `twoDigitStartDate`?

Comment: "the expected year is 2077" Why is this "expected"? There is no century information in the string "77". If you wanted century information, you needed to insist that the original string should _contain_ century information. Otherwise, specifying what "77" as a year should mean is up to _you_, but you are not doing anything about it.

Comment: @matt thank you for pointing out a duplicate question which has been down voted to oblivion by people. Unfortunately, the guy asked a valid question and the question was heavily down voted. I'm sure down voting is a great way to foster learning :)

Comment: Uncertain what you're referring to. The answer there, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907278/341994, is the answer you needed.

Comment: @asdiu Don't forget you can still accept an answer to your question even if it was marked as a duplicate. And to be fair, the duplicate only has one down vote. That's a long way from "down voted to oblivion" and "heavily down voted". And remember, having your question closed as a duplicate doesn't mean your question is bad in any way. I searched for a duplicate before posting my answer and didn't find one. Clearly matt searched on different terms. Duplicates allow people to find their answer easier in future searches.

Comment: sure @matt I saw your answer, but I was referring to the asker who was down voted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896265/8071224 . It was indeed the answer I needed, however the answer is being up voted but the bias against the asker is unfair is what I was trying to emphasize

Comment: There's no "bias against the asker". One person downvoted the question! If you can't accustom yourself to a world of up and down votes, you won't be happy on Stack Overflow. It's crowd sourced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DateFormatter twoDigitStartDate`. Create a date for whatever year you need.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.twoDigitStartDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 1980))
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
let _tmpDate = formatter.date(from: "10/01/77") // gives 2077
```

Change `1980` to whatever year meets your needs.